# How can I group array values into a new array?

Tags: php

I've got an array like this:

```
$a = [
     '53' => ['Foo', 1],
     '234' => ['Bar', 12],
     '343' => ['Bar', 22],
     '3' => ['Qux', 12],
     '34' => ['Foo', 1],
     ...]
```

I want to create an array that looks like this:

```
['1' => ['Foo', 'Foo'],
'12' => ['Bar', 'Qux']
'22' => ['Bar']]
```

That is, I want to look at the second element of each element in `$a`, and produce an array that uses this second element as an index in a new array, with the first element values added together in an array.

Hope this makes sense, there's probably a nice way to do it but my PHP array knowledge is somewhat lacking.

Answer (score 4):

```
$result = array();
foreach($a as $value) {
    $result[$value[1]][] = $value[0];
}
```